# ajax doesn't work on remote side but worked on localhost in mvc.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

It is working properly on localhost, but doesn't work after deployment. I am using jQuery to delete from controller: Here I am using  type: delete, but even get, POST nothing worked

```
 $("#btnDelete").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert("delete button clicked");
        bootbox.confirm("Do you really want to delete this User", function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "User/DoDelete/"+@Model.ID,
                    type:"Delete",
                    success: function() {

                       //  bootbox.alert("USer "+ @Model.ID+" Deleted successFully");
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","User")';
                    },
                    error:function() {
                        bootbox.alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

and my controller is

```
 [HttpDelete]
        public ActionResult DoDelete(int id)
        {
            context = new Cost();
            UserEmployee user = context.UserEmployees.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            try
            {
                context.UserEmployees.Remove(user);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I couldn't understand why it is working on localhost but not on deployment side.

Comment: Is the app setup as an application in IIS or virtual directory.  And, directly under default web sites?

Comment: as an application in IIS under default web sites

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
 url: '@Url.Action("DoDelete","User",new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = Model.ID}))',
```

or Use as below

```
url: '@Url.Action("DoDelete", "User", new { id = Model.ID})',
```

Comment: While this is likely the correct answer, you should not post code-only answers. Please explain *why* this will correct the user's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, writing it as below resolved the issue

```
    var newUrl='@Url.Action("DoDelete","User")?id='+@Model.ID;
```